# Distinguish local module with installed module

Tags: python, django

I installed `django` python module on my machine, and used it like this

a.py:

```
import django.core
...
```

then, I created an new file `django.py` in the same folder of file `a.py`, and re-run a.py, it throw import error, since it just imported my local `django.py`

```
  File "a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import django.core
  ImportError: No module named core
```

So, how to distinguish them when importing python module?

Comment: Don't.  Just don't do this.  Find another name.

Comment: thanks for your attention, but due to some reasons, I just have to use the same file name here...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `imp` module to import your script directly from a local path:

```
mymodule = imp.load_source('mymodule', 'django.py')
```

You can then use `mymodule` as if you had imported it normally.

Use caution, however; the python import internals must be subverted responsibly.

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily remove the current directory from `PYTHONPATH`:

```
$ python -c'import numpy.core' # works
$ touch numpy.py               # add conflicting module
$ python -c'import numpy.core' # it fails now
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2218, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy.core'; 'numpy' is not a package
$ python -c'import sys; sys.path.remove(""); import numpy.core' # works again
```

Needless to say, you should use such hacks sparingly if at all -- avoid  manipulating `sys.path` manually. Rename your local module, to avoid the conflict instead (move it inside a package at least e.g.: `your_package/numpy.py`).